# How to sign Java Webstart application for Java 8u141?

Tags: java, code-signing, java-web-start

It looks like there has been a change by Oracle similar to Java 7u45, where new manifest values needed to be set to run signed Java Webstart applications (see [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/faq.html#security_since_jdk1_7u45)).

Currently our signed application working with Java 8u131 does not start with Java8u141 with error message `Could not verify signing in resource: (arbitrary resource.jar)`

Can you still run your signed Webstart application with Java 8u141, i.e. do I have a special problem?

In the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u141-relnotes-3720385.html) is a note to security changes, but they don't look related to code signing. Also [crypto roadmap](https://www.java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html) looks like this release has not really changed code signing, despite Java 8u131 for example, where MD5 support was removed. But Java 8u131 is working for me and Maven Java Webstart Plugin also uses SHA-256-Digest.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace that came with this error ?

Comment: @PallaviSonal see the anwser from Bogdan O https://stackoverflow.com/a/45195897/1184842 , that is the very same error.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful hack!
I also had to change the following jar-Files: axis-1.4,
axis-jarpc-1.4,
axis-saaj-1.4,
xml-commons-resolver-1.2,
commons-httpclient-3.1. Now the web start application, with 137 jar-files included, starts correctly again. (Good, that I had only to patch 5 jar files, I think this are the older ones !!!)

Comment: This bug is addressed as part of the bug JDK-8184993 and the fix will be available in an out-of-cycle release of JDK 8u144, which is scheduled to be released on later hours of July 26, 2017.

Comment: @PallaviSonal The core bug linked is from 2005! https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6233323

Comment: @jan Yes, that was fixed in JDK 9 in 2016.

Comment: @PallaviSonal, also for the JRE 8u144? I'm not sure what they mean with 'Backports' if I check https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184993... I'm using JRE 1.8.0_141-b15 at this moment but the problem still exists...

Comment: @Perneel The issue has been fixed in a later version JDK 8u161(which is in early access) and the fix has been back-ported to JDK 8u144.  The JRE 1.8.0_141-b15 is already publicly released , so the fix is not there in this release. The new update release JDK 8u144 will be posted on Oracle'd download page sometime later today, you can download that and verify with that.

Comment: @PallaviSonal, ok thank you for the explanation! :)

Comment: @PallaviSonal, is there a way to see which build is currently available from the download page before installing?

Comment: @Perneel http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html , this page shows what is the currently available release version. Right now it shows Java SE 8u141 , when it is updated to Java SE 8u144, you can download it.

Comment: Ah silly me, i read '144' as '141' :) sorry! And thanks again!

Comment: The new version Java 8u144 is available now and fixed the webstart signing issue for me for my old versions again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a solution or more exactly a work-around to the problem. The jar in question was in our case the commons-httpclient-3.1.jar. The manifest contains the following entry

```
Name: org/apache/commons/httpclient
```

I added a / at the end and then I signed and re-deployed the application.

```
Name: org/apache/commons/httpclient/
```

This time the web start application started without any issues. In both cases the jar was signed with java 8u141, the jarsigner could verify the jar, but the webstart did not start in the first case. In my opinion this is a webstart bug.

Comment: I have just tested with the Java 8u152 b05 (early-access) and it works.

Comment: I removed only the dependency that was reported for me and it was working, too. I'll verify if that had the same problem.

Comment: can confirm, works with 8u152 b05 | relevant issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184993

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Java Webstart Application for **java 8u141**. It contains **commons-httpclient-3.1.jar** too. The problem exactly in this jar.

It looks like the algorithm of verification was changed. Now all manifest entries should have digest. I found out that this original jar has already contained one manifest entry *org/apache/commons/httpclient* without **digest**:

```
Name: org/apache/commons/httpclient
Implementation-Title: org.apache.commons.httpclient
Implementation-Version: 3.1
X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.2
Specification-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Specification-Title: Jakarta Commons HttpClient
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache
Extension-name: org.apache.commons.httpclient
X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.2
Specification-Version: 3.1
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
```

I fixed problem by changing ant jar task settings. I added to **exclude .MF files for 'zipfileset'** *(possible .SF, .RSA, .DSA files too). Also it can be required to change attribute 'filesetmanifest' = merge.*

It prevents appearing that manifest entry in final signed jar.

Answer (score 0):

There was a change affecting code signing: SHA-1 certificates were disabled.  This is mentioned in the release notes you linked to.  In particular they mention:

> A new constraint named `usage`, that when set, restricts the algorithm if it is used in a certificate chain for the specified use(s). Three usages are initially supported: `TLSServer` for TLS/SSL server certificate chains, `TLSClient` for TLS/SSL client certificate chains, and **`SignedJAR` for certificate chains used with signed JARs**.

(emphasis mine).  Note also that the release notes discuss the **entire certificate chain**.  So even if *your* signing cert uses a newer/stronger hash algorithm (SHA2 etc.), it could still be rejected if the *issuing authority's* certificate used SHA1.

More details at:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176536

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/288

Comment: In my understanding this does not affect code signing. But even if I'm wrong, why does this affect SHA-2 code signing certificates?

Comment: If there is a SHA1 cert in the chain, so why does jarsigner valide the jar as valid with "jar verified"? In first tests it even looks like really only this one jar is affected. I believe this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. My solution was to remove all directory entries in the jar (as they are useless normally) either by modifying the build scripts (ant:jar filesOnly="true") or with small groovy script to repack the jar without the dir entries.

This is definitely a JWS bug - I'm wondering how this went unnoticed by Oracle and if they will deliver a fast fix for this...

Answer (score 0):

I had problems for commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, axis-1.4.jar, xml-resolver-1.2.jar, oro-2.0.8.jar. Open the MANIFEST.MF add "/" in the end for name. re-build and sign the project and now it works