# Java Web Start not working after updating Java 8u141 - java.lang.SecurityException: digest missing for org/apache/commons/httpclient

Tags: java, java-web-start

After updating Java 8u141, my java web start application, run by jnlp stopped working. Do not download the application. And throws these exceptions below. Can someone help me?

```
com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Could not verify resource signature: http://www.example.com/myjar.jar
at com.sun.deploy.security.JarVerifier.authenticateJarEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.EnhancedJarVerifier.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.processJar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.access$2700(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$7.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToTempFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToCache(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Other:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: digest missing for org/apache/commons/httpclient
at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.JarVerifier.authenticateJarEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.EnhancedJarVerifier.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.processJar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.access$2700(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$7.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToTempFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToCache(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this same issue yesterday. This is what worked for me:

1. Use 7-Zip to open the original, unsigned jar which is throwing the JARSigningException. Probably a good idea to make a copy of the jar first in case anything goes wrong.
2. Open the META-INF folder and copy MANIFEST.MF somewhere to your PC.
3. Open the MANIFEST.MF copy in a text editor. Look for a line that says something like "Name: org/apache/commons/httpclient". There could be a few lines like this, depending on the jar. Below this line will probably be other lines like "Implementation-Vendor:...", "Specification-Title:...", etc. In any case, delete all "Name:..." lines and all the subsequent lines in each block.
4. Save the file, and replace the existing MANIFEST.MF in the jar with the edited version. 7-Zip allows files to be replaced inside jars in-situ.
5. Re-sign the jar and deploy.

It seems when jars get signed, the "Name:" lines in the manifest can wind up in the middle of the signed classes, which only now seems to be a problem with the release of Java 8u141 but were obviously fine before.

Comment: You just need to make sure the "Name:"  ends in / as described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html

Comment: Thanks cgull, that was exactly the solution to my mistake.

Comment: @WillT True for packages (not for classes).

Comment: They get removed when you resign the jar with only your key

Answer (score 2):

The issue is already fixed in 8u144, please upgrade to 8u144 to avoid this issue http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the commons-httpclient-3.1.jar library. Actually I believe it's a bug in the web start, as It worked before and it works with the 8u152 early access. The solution I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191576/how-to-sign-java-webstart-application-for-java-8u141/45209310#45209310)!

Comment: Although I agree regarding the Java-Bug, I just used this "opportunity" to update to org.apache.httpcomponents-httpclient-<version>.jar which is the new "host" of this code (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient) the old 3.1 version is from 2007 and not further supported...

Comment: I agree with Rainer. Here is the end of life statement: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/ I go for the httpcomponents one because it contains the digest. Even if workarounds exist for the current 3.1, who knows what comes in the future...

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is observed in signed JAR files whose manifest contains package version information[1] and does not have a trailing "/" in the name of the package (e.g.: Name: org/apache/xml/resolver). While we work towards resolving this issue, in the interim, users can work-around the issue as follows:
>
> NOTE: We recommend use of this workaround only if the distributor of the JAR files can "re-sign" the JAR files.
>
> 1. Extract the contents of the signed JAR file (e.g.: jar xf jar-file ).
> 2. Modify META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file and add a trailing “/” to the name of the package ( e.g.: Name: org/apache/xml/resolver/).
> 3. Remove the current signature files ( e.g.: rm -f META-INF/*.SF META-INF/*.RSA META-INF/*.DSA ).
> 4. Recreate the JAR file ( e,g.: jar cfm jar-file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF input-file(s) ).
>
> NOTE: You must use the jar utility. Other jar creation tools might re-introduce the issue.
>
> 5. Re-sign the JAR file.
>
> [1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/versioning/spec/versioning2.html#wp91706

Source:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u141-relnotes-3720385.html#KnownIssues

Answer (score 0):

This bug is addressed as part of the bug [JDK-8184993](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184993) and the fix will be available in an out-of-cycle release of JDK 8u144, which is scheduled to be released on later hours of July 26.